# Using a link/junction between web servers

Tags: symlink, windows-server-2012, mapped-drive, junction, mklink

I am trying to figure a way of connecting 2 web server's file systems together so they can access each others files natively. The servers are Windows 2012 and connected directly to the internet via public IPs. One server will be for storing large files, the other for the scripts and database (web server).

Essentially, I need a way to securely map a drive/folder between these servers so they show as folders e.g. the "d:\www\assets" folder is actually on the other sever (junction). As this link needs to be accessible to the SYSTEM (apache service) not a single user, a mapped drive is not ideal. Open, unsecured shares are also not a good idea.

Playing with junctions and links in the console doesn't show any method to provide a login/password to the remote system. The junction is created but inaccessible. If I map a drive, it is only for that user and not available to the SYSTEM account that Apache is using. If I run Apache as a user and map a drive as that user, it likely won't survive a reboot or work without being logged in on the console all the time.

Are there any native ways to hook these 2 servers together securely? I have full admin access on both servers and can create as many users as required, but they are not in a domain or potentially even on the same subnet.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use to a directory symlink via cifs/windows share considering you have have access to the local disk on one of the servers and the your sharing the the folder you want to symlink

for example:
on server a:
1. navigate to server a's local disk: d:\www\
2. mklink /d assets \serverb\assets

option 2DFS (unconfirmed)
if you can create a dfs on server on one user windows boxes, i believe you set dfs target to point folder assestes to \serverb\assets

Comment: Your option 1 requires login/password to be supplied otherwise the share would have to be open/public. mklink/junctions don't allow this. The servers are not part of a domain so have no shared users.